# DropDrop selection event refresh all the UpdatePanel in Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am using AJAX extension in visual studio 2005.
First of all i am created a Web custom control which contains Dropdown list.
I have also set AutoPostBack="true" for getting its SelectionEventChange event.

I am added this web control on another page inside a UpdatePanel.(i added dynamically on another page).

```
MyControl = (MyControl) LoadControl("MyControl.ascx")
```

My problem is when i select the values from dropdown it refersh my whole update panel.

What can i do please help me.
I searched in google and somebody says Use triggers

```
<Triggers>

<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

But on AJAX Extension i am not getting it please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

`Triggers` tag is part of update panel. Also look at some other important properties of UpdatePanel and search on how to use and referesh nested update panels.

Answer (score 0):

Add this web custom control inside another(other then one you are already having, that is, have [Multiple UpdatePanels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398867.aspx)) [`UpdatePanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.update.aspx), and call `.Update()` manually, in order to refresh only the web control.

Dont forget to set the [`UpdateMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode.aspx) to `Conditional`.

Comment: i tried that.it dynamically added the control so when timer runs it will unload the whole control from Page.

Comment: Can you explain, **so when timer runs it will unload**?